# Observing weird behavior regarding OutOfMemoryError in Java

Tags: java, out-of-memory

I was recently experimenting with OutOfMemoryError in Java and observed the below mentioned weird behavior for which I don't have any explanation.
Could some enthusiastic person please take a look and suggest possible explanations?

Thanks in advance!

Consider **3 runs** where each run is as follows:

```
javac SimulateOOM.java
java -Xmx100m -Xms100m SimulateOOM
```

**Run1:** Running code as it is:
**Output:**

> In finally
> Exception in thread
>   "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
>          at SimulateOOM.main(SimulateOOM.java:11)

**Run2:** Comment out *Statement 1* and uncomment *Statement 2*:
**Output:**

> Caught OOM!
>   In finally

**Run3** (***Mind blowing part***): Revert back to original code i.e. have *Statement 2* commented out and *Statement 1* uncommented. In addition, uncomment the *Statement block 3* i.e. uncomment all commented out statements present after *Statement Block 3*.
**Output:**

> Caught OOM!
>   In finally

**Questions I have as per my observations:**
1) How does ***Run 2*** but not ***Run 1*** manage to catch the exception when we know that Throwable is superclass of OutOfMemoryError?
2) How could uncommenting out some code (***Statement block 3***) possibly lead to expected behavior of Throwable being able to catch OOM?

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class SimulateOOM {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            int i = 0;
            Map<Integer, Integer> mp = new HashMap<>();
            if (true) {
                while (true) {
                    mp.put(new Integer(i), new Integer(i+1000000));
                    i += 1;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Throwable th) {          // ====== Statement 1 =====
        //catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {  // ====== Statement 2 =====
            System.err.println("Caught OOM!");
        }
        finally {
            System.err.println("In finally");
        }
    }

// ================= //
// Statement block 3
// ================= //
//    private static void simulateOOMCatchThrowable() {
//            try {
//            int i = 0;
//            Map<Integer, Integer> mp = new HashMap<>();
//            if (true) {
//                while (true) {
//                    mp.put(new Integer(i), new Integer(i+1000000));
//                    i += 1;
//                }
//            }
//        }
//        catch (Throwable th) {
//            System.err.println("Caught OOM!");
//        }
//        finally {
//            System.err.println("In finally");
//        }
//    }
//
//    private static void simulateOOMCatchOOM() {
//        try {
//            int i = 0;
//            Map<Integer, Integer> mp = new HashMap<>();
//            if (true) {
//                while (true) {
//                    mp.put(new Integer(i), new Integer(i+1000000));
//                    i += 1;
//                }
//            }
//        }
//        catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
//            System.err.println("Caught OOM!");
//        }
//        finally {
//            System.err.println("In finally");
//        }
//    }
}
```

Comment: It's not reproducible. When I run `for i in \`seq 1 100\`; do echo -n "$i: "; java -Xmx2m -Xms2m SimulateOOM; done;` I get 6 out of 100 times the output "Caught OOM!", otherwise a `OutOfMemoryError` bubbling up. So, even with the **same** code you can get different result.

Comment: What if 'System.err.println("Caught OOM!");" causes *another* OOM?  That would mask the original OOM and the SysOut leaving only the uncaught OOM

Comment: @Progman Thanks for checking!I tried same 100 runs multiple times but for me it never shows 'Caught OOM' :( Though given various cases above, I feel something fishy is going on here!

Comment: @DavidZimmerman That can happen! So to eliminate that case, I created those strings as static final class variables instead (so that memory gets allocated before OOM) but still observing the same behavior :(

Comment: @Dikshant But println(String) may allocate memory, EG a char[]